# SystemJS/Aurelia app breaks in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, aurelia, systemjs

I've been trying to get some tests in Phantom going, but Aurelia/SystemJS seems to break in Phantom.

I've tested it with my own app and the Aurelia contacts-app example, they slightly differently. I'll list the outputs here that I've captured:

app-contacts:

```
CONSOLE: INFO [aurelia] Aurelia Starting (from line #undefined in "undefined")
CONSOLE: DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin github:aurelia/templating-binding@0.11.0. (from line #undefined in "undefined")
TypeError: Attempting to define property on object that is not extensible.

  http://localhost:9001/:48 in defineProperty
  http://localhost:9001/:36
  http://localhost:9001/:29 in fastKey
  http://localhost:9001/:115
  http://localhost:9001/:10 in set
  http://localhost:9001/:51 in set
  http://localhost:9001/:14 in ensureOriginOnExports
  http://localhost:9001/:131
  http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7 in O
  http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7 in K
  http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7
  http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7
  http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7
  http://localhost:9001/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7
```

my application:

```
CONSOLE: Potentially unhandled rejection [2] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map
    at http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/:22
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/system.js:1)
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/system.js:1)
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/system.js:1)
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/system.js:1)
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/system.js:1)
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/system.js:1)
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/system.js:1)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/system.js:1
    at o (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7)
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7)
    at j (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7)
    at k (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7
    at O (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7)
    at K (http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7
    at http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7
    at http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7
    at http://127.0.0.1:8380/web-admin/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7 (from line #undefined in "undefined")
```

FWIW these both work fine in Chrome/FF and I'm running PhantomJS 1.9.8 on OS X 10.10

Also here's the phantom script I am using to test these and output from the console:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://localhost:9001/', function() {
  page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
  };
});
```

to run the contacts app (first example), run the following:

```
git clone git@github.com:aurelia/app-contacts.git
cd app-contacts
npm install && jspm install
gulp watch
```

This assumes you have `node`, `jspm` and `gulp` installed. Then you can run the above phantomjs script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Did you try a version lower than 1.9 of Phantom js ? I had trouble on osx with some 1.9 versions of Phantom

Answer (score 2):

`Map` is a pretty new structure. Use `npm install harmony-collections --save-dev` and add `"node_modules/harmony-collections/harmony-collections.min.js",` to the karma config.

Comment: Confirmed this approach works, though I went with the `es6-collections` shim as it appears to be more well maintained.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add "...js" to the karma config'? I don't know much about Karma. I'm using a karma.config.js file created by a Yeoman generator but there's no list of files to include or something. Can you give me a few more details, please?

Comment: in the karma.conf add it to the 'files array' like this:  "files: [
  './node_modules/harmony-collections/harmony-collections.min.js' 
]"

Comment: Thanks. Now I got it, and it works. In my case the value of `files` is being generated by a function, so it was more obscure to me.